# How can I Integrate Alfresco with Wordpress by Single Sign On?

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, integration, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to configure a single sign on between Wordpress and Alfresco, for this reason I added WordPress OAuth2 Provider Plugin on my wordpress administration panel.  [wordpress plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVGwu.png)

I created a client and inserted a redirect uri to my alfresco, and the plugin gave me a key and a secret. Right now, after logging in to wordpress, I go to my blog and click on the link to go on alfresco, but the page with url:

`http://localhost:8080/share/page/repository?oauth=authorize&response_type=code&client_id=**************&client_secret=**************&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fauth%3Dssoe`

[alfresco login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq39d.png)

Ask me username and password again! How can I configure Alfresco, so that it is logged with those credentials? Thanks to anyone who wants to help me, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco includes multiple authentication systems, including Alfresco Database, Active Directory, LDAP, Kerberos, External, and can be set up to authenticate with one of them or a combination of them. Normally these authentication systems cover most of the authentication combinations and mechanisms needed.

You can also use alfresco custom authentication sub-system,
In this you need to pass the condition when you wanted to authenticate a user,
this is some snippet of java class for authentication

```
     package org.alfresco.tutorial.repo.security.authentication;

import net.sf.acegisecurity.Authentication;

import org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException;
import org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationComponent;
import org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class CustomAuthenticationComponentImpl extends AbstractAuthenticationComponent {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CustomAuthenticationComponentImpl.class);

   /**
    * Some custom properties that could be used to inject a remote login server hostname and port.
    * Not used at the moment but demonstrates property injection in custom authentication component.
    */
    private String remoteAuthenticatorHostname;
    private String remoteAuthenticatorPort;

    public void setRemoteAuthenticatorHostname(String remoteAuthenticatorHostname) {
        this.remoteAuthenticatorHostname = remoteAuthenticatorHostname;
    }

    public void setRemoteAuthenticatorPort(String remoteAuthenticatorPort) {
        this.remoteAuthenticatorPort = remoteAuthenticatorPort;
    }

    public void authenticateImpl(String userName, char[] password) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
           LOG.debug("Login request(" + remoteAuthenticatorHostname + ":" + remoteAuthenticatorPort +
           ") : [userName=" + userName + "][password=" + String.valueOf(password) + "]");
        }

        // Do your custom authentication here, and then set the current user (in this example we are only allowing
        // john to authenticate successfully, and we don't check pwd)
        // You would typically connect to the remote authentication mechanism to verify username/pwd...
        if (StringUtils.equals(userName, "john") || isGuestUserName(userName) ||
                getDefaultAdministratorUserNames().contains(userName)) {
            setCurrentUser(userName);
        } else {
            String msg = "Login request: username not recognized [userName=" + userName + "]";
            LOG.error(msg);
            throw new AuthenticationException(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * The default is not to support token base authentication
     */
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication token) throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new AlfrescoRuntimeException("Authentication via token not supported");
    }

    /**
     * This authentication component implementation allows guest login
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean implementationAllowsGuestLogin() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please refer this [documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-authentication.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to configure Alfresco for External auth, then add a proxy in front of Alfresco that can deal with your OAuth2 tokens. Alfresco does not natively support OAuth2. So unless you use External you'll have to write the authentication code yourself.